# a single decisive word for a "positive result"

Tags: single-word-requests

It says:

> The sweeping prevalence of technology is an undeniable fact today. Both
>   fruits and repercussions of such prevalence have reached epidemic
>   proportions.

Can fruit mean a positive result, here? and if yes, is it because of the context (mainly due to its contrast to repercussion) or it independently sounds that way?
Dictionaries are not forthcoming enough about this, attributing fruit to both
results and consequences(implicitly conveying a negative result). So my question is:

What's really a decisive, yet general word for a positive result? I'm saying "general" to rule out the words like harvest[n.] which mean "result of an **effort**"
I also came across similar questions here on the website, but they seem fail to be frank enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit, because the obvious answer to the question in your title is *pregnant*.

Comment: What about: "Both the pros and cons of such prevalance..."

Comment: Elliott Frisch, I'm new to here. Do you mind telling me what I'm supposed to do? remove the whole question? change the title, or what, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For greater clarity, I would have used "benefits and drawbacks" instead of"fruits and repercussions".

Comment: In my reading of the two phrases, “fruits and repercussions” refers to the whole phrase “prevalence of technology”;  “benefits and drawbacks” does not, but only to prevalence itself.  That is, the former emphasizes technology as the subject, while the latter does not.